# Reading environment variables of various types

Tags: go

I need to extract some data from the environment variables using Go. This data can be string, boolean or integer, so I ended up writing three functions.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func getStrEnv(key string) string {
    val := os.Getenv(key)
    if val == "" {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("some error msg"))
    }
    return val
}

func getIntEnv(key string) int {
    val := getStrEnv(key)
    ret, err := strconv.Atoi(val)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("some error"))
    }
    return ret
}

func getBoolEnv(key string) bool {
    val := getStrEnv(key)
    ret, err := strconv.ParseBool(val)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("some error"))
    }
    return ret
}
```

Which works, but in a language like Python, I would just create one function `getEnv(key, type_var)`, which would go through various passes depending on the `type_var` provided. Is there a way to produce similar result with Go?

Comment: Not a code review, but I wrote https://github.com/walles/env to solve this very problem using generics. Check it out!

Answer (score 12):

Go is statically typed. Every variable has a static type, that is, exactly one type known and fixed at compile time. You are not in dynamically typed Python anymore.

You could use reflection, BUT DON'T!

> [Common difficulties with
>   reflection](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/abpF-Ykd0Z0/discussion)
>
> If people are new to Go, they shouldn't be using reflection at all.
>
> -rob

Your functions are specializations of `os.Getenv`. Revise the function names to `getenvStr`, `getenvInt`, and `getenvBool`.

> [`os.Getenv`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv) retrieves the value of the environment variable named
>   by the key. It returns the value, which will be empty if the variable
>   is not present.

There is often nothing wrong when an environment variable is empty. Instead of `panic`ing, return a named `error`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

var ErrEnvVarEmpty = errors.New("getenv: environment variable empty")

func getenvStr(key string) (string, error) {
    v := os.Getenv(key)
    if v == "" {
        return v, ErrEnvVarEmpty
    }
    return v, nil
}

func getenvInt(key string) (int, error) {
    s, err := getenvStr(key)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    v, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return v, nil
}

func getenvBool(key string) (bool, error) {
    s, err := getenvStr(key)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    v, err := strconv.ParseBool(s)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    return v, nil
}

func main() {}
```

References:

[Package reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)

[The Laws of Reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

Comment: Since Go 1.18 I think generics is the right tool for this, see my answer about github.com/walles/env.

Answer (score 0):

You can also abstract an interface, so you can implement other `ConfigSource`s later (e.g. file based).

```
package main
import (
    "strconv"
    "os"
)

type ConfigSource interface {
    GetString(name string) string
}

type Config struct {
    ConfigSource
}
func (c *Config) GetString(name string) string {
    if nil == c.ConfigSource {
        return ""
    }
    return c.ConfigSource.GetString(name)
}
func (c *Config) GetBool(name string) bool {
    s := c.GetString(name)
    i, err := strconv.ParseBool(s)
    if nil != err {
        return false
    }
    return i
}
func (c *Config) GetInt(name string) int {
    s := c.GetString(name)
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 0)
    if nil != err {
        return 0
    }
    return i
}
func (c *Config) GetFloat(name string) float64 {
    s := c.GetString(name)
    i, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
    if nil != err {
        return 0
    }
    return i
}
type EnvGetter struct {}
func (r *EnvGetter) GetString(name string) string {
    return os.Getenv(name)
}

func main() {
    c := &Config{ConfigSource:EnvGetter{}}
    println("HOME:", c.GetString("HOME"))
    println("SHLVL:", c.GetInt("SHLVL"))
}
```

Comment: Your code has compile errors.